# MySQL request with variables

Tags: mysql

I have table *tokens*, consisting of

- *user_id* - token ower
- *token* - access token
- *end_date*: datetime of token's expiration

I need make request receiving a token returning user_id and the validity of token(end_date not yet come)

pseudo code:

```
select user_id end_date 
from tokens where token = @input_token
into @user_id @end_date

if @user_id is not none:
   select @user_id, now() < @end_date

select "invalid token"
```

Can it be wrote without variables?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a CASE statement but you might want to think about what you want to return from the results of your query.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-statement/

```
SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN user_id IS NOT NULL THEN
        user_id
    ELSE
        NULL
    END CASE) AS user_id,
    (CASE WHEN user_id IS NOT NULL THEN
        (now() < end_date)
    ELSE
        NULL
    END CASE) AS valid_token
FROM tokens
WHERE token = @input_token
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try add `error_message` with something in it if `user_id` is null:

```
select
    user_id,
    now() < end_date as is_valid_date,
    if(user_id is null, 'invalid_token', '') as error_message
from tokens where token = @input_token;
```